# BBCodes for bio doesn't work as I'd hope

Tags: php, html, bbcode

I have a bio (personal message) that displays on a user's profile page. I have added BBCodes that work ([b]bold[/b]), but when I'm gone and come back to change the bio later, it shows HTML tags. I would also like to remove HTML and PHP tags. As of now, it would be critical if someone could just type in PHP code into their bio and delete the table. heres my BBCode / change bio code:

```
<div class="fl">
        <!--BB-codes-->
    <?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "table") or die ("Could not connect to database");

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if(isset($_POST['bio_message']))
        {
                $text = $_POST['bio_message'];
                $text = stripslashes($text);
                $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
                $text = nl2br($text);

                $text = preg_replace('#\[b\](.+)\[/b\]#isU', '<b>$1</b>', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('#\[i\](.+)\[/i\]#isU', '<i>$1</i>', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('#\[u\](.+)\[/u\]#isU', '<u>$1</u>', $text);

                $text = preg_replace('#\[img\](.+)\[/img\]#isU', '<img src="$1" />', $text);
        }

            $id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET bio = '$text' WHERE id = '$id'";
            $db->query($sql);
        }else{}
    ?>
</div>
            <div class="title-wrapper" style="margin:auto; width:60%;">
                <h3 class="widget-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Change Bio</h3>
                <div class="title-content">
                    <form method="post" action="/settings/change-bio">
                        <div class="fl">Bio :</div><a href="" class="a fr" style="font-size:11px; text-decoration:underline;">BB-codes</a><br/>
                        <textarea maxlength="2000" onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',2000);" placeholder="User has not set any bio yet..." id="bio_message" name="bio_message" class="textarea" style="max-width:100%; max-height:160px; width:100%; height:160px;"><?php
                            $id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";


                            $result = $db->query($SQL);

                            /* numeric array */

                            /* associative array */
                            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                            printf ($row["bio"]);

                            $result->free();
                            ?></textarea>

                        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Set Bio" />
                        <input disabled  maxlength="3" size="3" value="2000" id="counter"> Characters remaining.
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Er... You forgot to escape the other `/`. You should do it with `\/`.

Comment: where are you pointing at? the bb codes work it self, but im scared because it allowes html and php tags to be allowed. this can get people to delete my database and such.

Comment: ok so it doesnt allow php but i dont want it to display html tags, and if it could just replace them with bbcodes or and not allow html at all

Answer (score 0):

The program is storing the post *with BBCodes parsed,* and thus that is what is shown in the text area. You need to update the table **before** you parse the BBCodes, and then parse them when you present the bio to a user. Alternatively, you could also have an extra column in the database for the source of the post.